# Issues converting istream to ifstream while passing std::cin into an argument

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, ifstream, pass-by-value, istream

I am currently implementing a text-file based testing UI that will take mocked up user inputs from a text file (line-by-line) to simulate real user input instead of using `std::cin`.

The issue arises when I attempt to pass `std::cin` into `std::ifstream` parameter; the issue persists whether it is by reference or by value.

Function:

```
void ZoinkersEngine::displayMainMenu(User& currentUser, std::ifstream& in) {
//need a function to check the role level of the user here

//DEMO (Mock-up) of Menu
std::string option = "";
do {
    std::cout << std::string(40, '\n');
    std::cout << "Successfully logged in...\n\n\n";
    std::cout << "Main Menu:\n";
    std::cout << "[0] Order Plan\n";
    std::cout << "[1] Generate Plan\n\n";

    std::cout << "Please input number of selected option: ";
    // std::cin >> option;
    in >> option;

    if (option == "0") {
        currentUser.calculateExhibitFav(zoinkersDirectory);
        currentUser.orderPlan(zoinkersDirectory);
    }
    else if (option == "1") {
        currentUser.calculateExhibitFav(zoinkersDirectory);
        currentUser.generatePlan(zoinkersDirectory);
    }
    else if (option == "cancel" || option == "Cancel") {
        break;
    }
} while (option != "cancel" || option != "Cancel");}
```

Call To Function:

```
engine.displayMainMenu(currentUser, std::cin);
```

Error:

```
cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::istream' to 'std::ifstream'
```

I can not figure this out; as far as I know `ifstream` is derived from the `istream` base class, thus the compiler should be able to cast it.

EDIT #1: Current IDE is Visual Studios 2017; answers must also compile on g++ and work on linux.

Comment: Such a conversion is not possible. Make the parameter in the function definition be an istream   reference.

Comment: You cannot pass `std::cin` "into" a `std::ifstream` parameter because `std::cin` is not a `std::ifstream`. Furthermore, even if it was, you would not be able to pass it by value anyway, as you're doing. You won't be able to pass any real `std::ifstream` into your function, not just `std::cin`.

Comment: "ifstream is derived from the istream base class".  Another way to say that is, "ifstream 'is-a' istream".  No cast implied. No cast required.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik because that is not possible is there a way to implement the same logic without creating separate function calls for the different input sources?

Answer (score 2):

There is no implicit down casting.  If you want the function to take an input stream then it should have the signature

```
void ZoinkersEngine::displayMainMenu(User& currentUser, std::istream& in)
                                                             ^      ^
                                                             |      reference here
                                                             istream, not ifstream
```

And now you can pass to it any stream that is an `istream` or derived from one.

This is necessary as

1. you cannot pass a stream by value if it is an lvalue since streams are not copyable
2. casting from a base class to a derived class can only be done when the base class was originally a derived class.  This is also only done with pointers otherwise the derived to base class conversion would [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) and you lose the derived class part

Comment: Thank you for reply! This is all clear and makes sense to me. However, I am now at square one and cannot seem to think of a way to implement a selective input stream (from a file and std::cin). Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JaredF. What do you mean?  With the way I have it in my answer you can pass `cin` or your own file stream to the function.

Comment: Ahhhh, please excuse my ignorance. I didn't realize you could use a file as an input stream with istream. Now that I say it outloud it seems like common sense! Thanks for all the help!!!

Comment: @JaredF. No problem.  Glad to help.